# How to manipulate the string data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set something like this:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~id,
   1,
   2,   
   3,
   4,
   5,)
```

Now, I want to get only one row that shows the below data:

```
desired_data <- tribble(
  ~query,
  "id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5"
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `sep` and `collapse` argument.

```
paste(names(data), data$id, sep = " = ", collapse = " OR ")
#[1] "id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5"
```

Or with `paste0`

```
paste0(names(data), " = ", data$id, collapse = " OR ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code with `paste0`, i.e.:

```
desired_data <- tibble(query = paste0(paste0("id = ",data$id), collapse = " OR "))
```

such that

```
> desired_data
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  query                                         
  <chr>                                         
1 id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  summarise(query =  str_c(names(.), id, sep = ' = ', collapse= ' OR '))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  query                                         
#  <chr>                                         
#1 id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR id = 4 OR id = 5
```